The following packages have unmet dependencies: libnvidia-decode-535 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-535 (= 535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not
I am trying to run sudo apt upgrade command on Jetson Orin NX that has been flashed with Jetpack 6.0 but I keep getting this error message:
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-decode-535 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-535 (= 535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

When I try to run sudo apt --fix-broken install I get this output:
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools dkms libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil-dev
  libavutil56 libexif-dev libgdcm-dev libgphoto2-dev libnvidia-cfg1-535
  libnvidia-common-535 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-encode-535
  libnvidia-fbc1-535 libopencv-superres4.5d libopencv-videostab4.5d
  libpostproc55 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libva-x11-2
  libvdpau1 libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1 linux-headers-5.15.0-117
  linux-headers-5.15.0-117-generic linux-headers-generic nvidia-dkms-535
  nvidia-firmware-535-535.183.01 nvidia-kernel-common-535
  nvidia-kernel-source-535 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings python-pkg-resources
  python-setuptools screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-535
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-535
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 395 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 168 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 295365 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-535_535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64.
deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-535:arm64 (535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-535_535
.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so', which is also in p
ackage nvidia-l4t-cuda 36.3.0-20240506102626
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-535_535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64
.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried rebooting the system, which didn't work. I also tried running sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt --fix-broken install again, but that outputs the same error message. I also tried the solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1386209/how-to-solve-this-dependencies-apt-fix-broken-install, but that also didn't solve my problem.
Does anyone know what could be the source of this problem and is there a solution to it?

I do not see that you ran a sudo apt update to update the database before the sudo apt upgrade.

The error message means that you are trying to have two incompatible packages installed at the same time. You cannot do that. You must pick one and uninstall the other. It's the apt-solver meaning of "broken"
It does NOT mean that any packages are corrupt or don't work (the human meaning of "broken")
And a solution is right there is your output:
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
...
libnvidia-cfg1-535 libnvidia-common-535 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535
...
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

"no longer required" means that one of those packages is awaiting removal already. It even tells you how.

Thanks for the response. When I run sudo apt autoremove I get the same error message like when I run sudo apt upgrade. Is there anything else I can do? Also, do you know how I could prevent this from happening in the future?

Your output seem clear that trying to install libnvidia-compute-535 caused this problem. Apt will keep trying to install the package. Stop apt by using sudo apt-mark remove libnvidia-compute-535. The easiest way to prevent problems like these is by reading the apt output.
